# How to create Excel chart that shows how many times specified dates appear in a date range?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Lets say that I have such data:

2014-05-26
2014-07-02
2014-11-06
2014-11-06
2015-01-08
2015-06-06

Basically what I want is an Excel chart where on horizontal axis there would be a date range ranging nicely from lets say 2014-01-01 till 2015-12-12 and on vertical axis there should be numbers from 0 to lets say 10. In the chart itself I want to see how many times specified dates above appear in date range. For example there are no 2014-02-02 on the provided dates list above, therefore such date should be represented as 0 in the chart. Date 2014-05-26 should be represented as 1 and date 2014-11-06 should be represented as 2.

How can I achieve that? Excel 2010

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of all unique values in your list of dates by copying the list and using `Data -> Remove Duplicates`. Then in the column adjacent to your new distinct list (which let's say starts in `B2` and runs down to `B20`), use a formula like (in `C2 in our example, then copied down for the whole list):

```
=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$20,B2)
```

This will then give you the counts for each unique date, which you should easily be able to create a chart from.

Comment: The count for each unique date will always be 1, since they are unique in the first place. And it's not that I want to count how many similar dates there are in the range, I want to see where they are located in the specified time frame.

Comment: Ok, I was confused by your question then: "I want to see how many times specified dates above appear in date range". So you **don't** want to see how many times specified dates appear? Why would your graph have a y-axis that has "numbers from 0 to lets say 10" if no dates will appear more than once? Plus, you have a duplicated date in your example data: `2014-11-06`, so I'm pretty confused about what you're asking for.

Comment: I'll try to explain in different words. I set time frame from lets say 2014-01-01 till 2015-12-12. One long line with no gaps. If some kind of event occurred on day 2014-05-26 I want to see that on my graph as a column or a dot that would be equal to value "1" (only one event occurred on the day 2014-05-26). Everything else in this example must remain at value "0" but those dates/values must still be shown on the graph. If two event occurred on the same day (for example on the day 2014-11-06), the I want it to be shown on the graph as a column or a dot that would be equal to value "2".